# Barrier Option Pricing in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, quantitative-finance

We have a barrier call option of European type with strike price  `K>0` and a barrier value

`0 < b< S0` ,

where `S_0` is the starting price.According to the contract, the times  `0<t_1<...<t_k<T`  the price must be checked `S(t_k)>b`  for every `k`.

Assuming the `S(t)` is described with the binomial option model with `u=1.1`  and  `d = 0.9`,`r=0.05`,`T=10`, and `t_1=2,t_2=4` and `t-3=7` the times that the asset must be checked.Also consider the `S_0=100,K=125` and the barrier `b=60`.

My attempt is the following :

```
# Initialise parameters
S0 = 100      # initial stock price
K = 125       # strike price
T = 10        # time to maturity in years
b = 60        # up-and-out barrier price/value
r = 0.05      # annual risk-free rate
N = 4         # number of time steps
u = 1.1       # up-factor in binomial models
d = 0.9       # ensure recombining tree
opttype = 'C' # Option Type 'C' or 'P'

def barrier_binomial(K,T,S0,b,r,N,u,d,opttype='C'):
    #precompute values
    dt = T/N
    q = (1+r - d)/(u-d)
    disc = np.exp(-r*dt)
    
    # initialise asset prices at maturity
    S = S0 * d**(np.arange(N,-1,-1)) * u**(np.arange(0,N+1,1))
        
    # option payoff
    if opttype == 'C':
        C = np.maximum( S - K, 0 )
    else:
        C = np.maximum( K - S, 0 )
            
    # check terminal condition payoff
    C[S >= b] = 0
            
    # backward recursion through the tree
    for i in np.arange(N-1,-1,-1):
        S = S0 * d**(np.arange(i,-1,-1)) * u**(np.arange(0,i+1,1))
        C[:i+1] = disc * ( q * C[1:i+2] + (1-q) * C[0:i+1] )
        C = C[:-1]
        C[S >= H] = 0
    return C[0]

barrier_binomial(K,T,S0,b,r,N,u,d,opttype='C')
```

I receive nothing because something is wrong and I don’t know what

But is it a simulation ?

Any help from someone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you are using `C[S >= H] = 0`, but your barrier param is defined as `b`. Also you are filling the array `C` with 0s only, so check the payoff condition. In general, I find it much easier looping through matrices when working with tree models.

Comment: Can you provide your code?It will help me understand what you are saying.And it will help in general to understand this kind of models